# Xcode Buttons overflowing screen

Tags: xcode, swift

I am trying to create a simple keypad in Xcode, using swift.  I set up my keys how I want them to look, but when I run it, half of the buttons are off of the screen.  Depending on the simulator, it can be pretty bad.

I was looking at this project:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/UnitTests/Introduction/Intro.html

It is a simple calculator application with a bunch of buttons.  When I run this app, the buttons do not flow off of the screen, no matter which simulator I use.  I thought that this would have something to do with constraints, but there are no constraints on any of the buttons.

Can someone please tell me what it is about this app that keeps the buttons from flowing off the right edge of the screen?  I've spent the last hour comparing it to what I have, and I cannot find a difference.

Comment: Do you have `Use Size Classes` turned on? In your storyboard click on a view then `File Inspector` and check `Use Size Classes` is turned off, otherwise you will have to set the auto layout attributes to get the view working correctly on different sized simulators.

Comment: That made the difference.  The only problem that I'm having now is that the buttons are all left aligned.  I need them to be centered in the view.